# SuperSu doesnt show up on TWRP

Tags: root-access, twrp, superuser, supersu, samsung-galaxy-j7

I installed TWRP successfully. On my phone i downloaded the SuperSu Zip. When i click install on TWRP it doesnt show up. Can Anyone tell me what to do to make it show up.

Info:
-Phone = J7 (2016) j700T
-NETWORK T-Mobile

Comment: Did you browse to the /sdcard/Downloads folder?

Comment: @acejavelin there are *plenty* of bugs with TWRP and the Samsung J series. But, to the point, TWRP can Install SuperSU itself, no extra files. Try that!

Comment: I tried that but SuperSu just doesnt show up on TWRP when i click install. I checked everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong version of TWRP. Many links for the J700T are posted in the forums and it took me a while to get a developer to give me the correct link.

For Twrp, flash [TWRP-3.0.2.0-J700T](http://download2201.mediafire.com/bw1d6brbkclg/b3ba4e6e6w6f1da/odintwrp-3.0.2-0-j700t.zip) with ODIN.
Put SuperSu on the internal SD if you have to, but TWRP *should* be able to read the external SD.

My source is [this thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=70283591&postcount=446) on XDA Developers. Afterwards, go to page 1 for detailed instructions on installing SuperSu and enabling Data partition backups in TWRP. (Hint: you need to backup your apps with Titanium Backup before formatting your Data!)